# Integrate Twitter picture gallery in my own iphone app- Objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, twitter, gallery

I am making an iphone app, and I would like to integrate a picture gallery. 
My idea is to have a previsualization of some pictures, and once you tap one of them, you can see the others by sliding.

The thing is that I would like to make a previsualization like Twitter app has in the Profile screen. In this kind of previsualization, you can slide the thumbnails, and once you see a picture that you are interested in, you tap on it and you see it.

Do you know any library which is able to do this?

I am waiting for your answers.

Thank  youuu

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to something done in the WWDC 2012 Collection View demo, which can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/). If their demo isn't right, you still almost definitely want to use a collection view with a flow layout.